# Error:Property 'device' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Im trying to build an application to capture audio recording. I have added all plugins.

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(this.captureSuccess, this.captureError, {limit: 2});
```

It is giving the error *device is not exist in navigator.*

```
navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
```

It is giving *Property 'notification' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.*

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please run `ionic info` and include the output in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is although you have your plugins installed, They are not resolved by Typescript.

One solution is install `typings` for the plugins you trying to use: See [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-typings-to-install-cordova-from-github-definitelytyped/46713/3) answer in Ionic forum.

Or you could use Ionic Native that is a TypeScript wrapper for Cordova/PhoneGap plugins that make it easy adding any native functionality.

Take a look at these:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/